# Find rows in matlab table

Tags: matlab, slice

I'm new to Matlab, sorry for this very simple question. Given a table:

```
>> T = table(['MALE';'MALE';'FEMA';'FEMA';'FEMA'],[38;43;38;40;49],[71;69;64;67;64],[176;163;131;133;119])

T = 

    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4
    ____    ____    ____    ____

    MALE    38      71      176 
    MALE    43      69      163 
    FEMA    38      64      131 
    FEMA    40      67      133 
    FEMA    49      64      119
```

How can one access to the rows which contain `'FEMA'` only ?

*Naively*, I would write as:

```
>> T(T.Var1 == 'FEMA',:)
```

to get

```
ans = 

Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4
____    ____    ____    ____

FEMA    38      64      131 
FEMA    40      67      133 
FEMA    49      64      119
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with tables. Have you tried something like `T({'FEMA'},:)`? Source: [matlab help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) > index using names.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I tried this, you would have to name the rows first and when I try `T.Properties.RowNames = {'MALE';'MALE';'FEMA';'FEMA';'FEMA'}` I get the error `Duplicate row name: 'MALE'.` so I guess that row names need to be unique

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dan for the info. I should probably consider familiarizing myself with newer versions of matlab (I'm stuck at R2012b). Then I wouldn't have to guess:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using `ismember`:

```
T(ismember(T.Var1,'FEMA','rows'),:)
```

FYI you could have declared `Var1` as a cell array and not force elements to have the same number of characters:

```
T = table({'MALE';'MALE';'FEMALE';'FEMALE';'FEMALE'},[38;43;38;40;49],[71;69;64;67;64],[176;163;131;133;119])
```

and then you can drop the `'rows'` argument

```
T(ismember(T.Var1,'FEMALE'),:)
```

Comment: what a neat solution! I am familiarizing myself with tables in matlab and trying to learn to do things properly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @A.K. I haven't worked much with tables, there might be a better way. That's how I would do it if `T` was a matrix / cell array though

Comment: @A.K. if you're going to be using tables btw, then you should really give your columns better names

Comment: sure you're right:) I just grabbed a simple example from Mathworks to present my problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
T2 = T(T.Var1=='F',:)
```

I assume you already looked at the help, but basically this is because it is a cell not char. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html

So, if you wanted to match the full string, use string comp

```
T2 = T(strcmp(T.Var1, {'FEMA'}),:)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was sure that matlab can offer something more "accessible" for tables than using "strcmp" or "ismember".